# Making Rascal structures looking better

Tags: rascal

To keep structures clear is it possible to name them. So essentially I asking for a 'struct' in Rascal. So eg:

```
list[tupple[map[str,int],int]]
```

to:

```
treeLabel :: str
occurences :: int
treeData :: map[treeLabel,int]
treeNode :: tupple[treeData,int]
tree :: list[treeNode]
tree x=[];
```

Tx

Jos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using Abstract Data Types?

See [Rascal Tutor](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Declarations/AlgebraicDataType/AlgebraicDataType.html). The above could then look like this:

```
data MyStruct = ms(str treeLabel, 
                   int occurrence, 
                   map[treeLabel, int] treeData,
                   tuple[TreeData td, int n] treeNode,
                   list[TreeNode] tree);
```

given some variable `m` with a `myStruct` value you can access elements with the usual dot notation:

```
m.treeLabel;
m.treeLabel = "xyz";
```

etc.

Comment: Tx that is what i am looking for

Comment: And keyword parameters for constructors are also nice: `data MyStruct ms(str myLabel = "defaultLabel");`